# Microsoft Graph API on Outlook calendar without checking inside private events

Tags: azure, api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have a question on how Microsoft Graph API works when collecting users' private events (only visible to him/herself) from outlook.

I'd like to collect sets of occupied time of users' calendars in my organization for automated meeting arrangement,
but for private concerns I'm compelled to achieve it without being able to see the contents of private events.(i.e. Meeting title, those involved and description)
Such scopes as `Calendars.Read` allow me to even check inside the private events.

Is there any alternative usage on Microsoft Graph API to avoid it to get only occupied time sets?
Thank you.

c.f.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findMeetingTimes`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/findmeetingtimes-example